# Android Studio not resolving dependencies for app engine module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio to create a Google App Engine Module. I followed the first step to use the UI to generate an App Engine Module, but after that I got stuck on the part about adding dependencies. When I try to use **File > Project Structure > + > Add Library Dependencies**, none of three dependencies listed in the tutorial show up in the list of available libraries.  After reading other StackOverflow posts, I tried the following:

- I updated Android Studio, Android Build Tools, Google Play services, and the Google Repository to the newest version.
- I tried adding the dependencies manually by writing compile statements in the backend module build.gradle file (e.g. compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk').  Then the sync failed and Android Studio gave me the following error: Failed to resolve: com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk
- I tried **File > Restart / Invalidate Cache**
- I tried using Android Studio on a different computer

All this, yet no success. Below are my gradle files, in case they are of use. Although I would be surprised if they would be, since I just followed the app engine part of the tutorial.

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

backend module build.gradle:

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'

}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

Android Studio gives me the error message mentioned above on the last three dependencies in the above file when I try to sync.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.